# German word for "passphrase"

Tags: translation, english-to-german, word-choice

What is a good translation of the word passphrase into German? I refer, of course, to the technical term. I.e. when used with encryption.

Would it be legit to use the old, but arguably suitable, German word: **Losung**?

---

What do you folks think about:

- Kennwortsatz
- Schlüsselsatz

Comment: Except for "Passwort", which denotes a single word, the only thing that comes to my mind is "Losung", googling a little brought forth "Parole" which is not any "newer" than Losung..

Comment: Parole and Losungs sounds both wrong for me - it implicit a military or criminal usage in real life - not a IT usage. I would use passphrase as a foreign word or maybe `Passwort-Satz` or `Passwörter`or `Passwort-Kombination`. Attention:  `Passwort-Satz` is sometimes used as a memory hook for a password.

Comment: Why not simply Passphrase? There are hundreds of technical terms where German does not have an own word.

Comment: @Em1: because I am looking for a *German* word. It's a rich language. There are loads of technical terms taken from English which I use everyday, and still I prefer "Rechner" to "computer" and "Speicher" to "RAM" and "Festplatte" to "hard drive". Besides, even "Kennwort" sounds better than "Paßwort". Also, how would you pronounce it? English pronounciation?

Comment: Deutsche Aussprache. Phrase gibt's auch im Deutschen. Und Passphrase wird auch in deutschen Texten verwendet. Wenn man mal etwas googelt, findet man da einiges. - Also wenn ich ne Antwort schreiben würde, wäre diese definitiv "Passphrase".

Comment: Passphrase ist für mich 100% ein Deutsches Wort

Comment: I like the idea of using *Losung*. Its meaning is exactly the original meaning of a password, but without the implication of a single word. The only downside is that you will often not be understood ;)

Comment: @Emanuel: Passphrase is a terrible word for a simple thing, and is not understandable by DAUs.

Comment: My two cents: I'd strongly advise against "Losung". My first association would be "feces of wild animals"... Apart from that, the second meaning ("passphrase") is indeed a bit old-fashioned and somehow I associate primarily military usage with it. If I heard someone talk about a passphrase using the term "Losung", I'd probably get the impression of a die-hard Protector of the Purity of the German Language - like those who insist on "E-Post" * cringe *

Comment: @Mac: that's fine with me if you get that impression, I've been accused of worse things. "E-Post" only sounds okay when it's the *system* as opposed to an individual *message*, though. Anything else is ridiculous. Also, I know the meaning that you associate first, but only because one of my deceased relatives worked in that area. It's not the first thing I associate, though :)

Comment: @Mac: Worse (?) than that, my first thought when reading "Losung" used as a term for passphrase would be of incapable translators who do a word-by-word translation with dictionaries without having an idea what the text they are translating means. Happens way too often in manuals and the like.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The mostly used German word for both, a password and a passphrase is "[Passwort](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Passwort)".

For example see this guide from the [Bundesamt für Sicherheit und Informationstechnik](https://www.bsi-fuer-buerger.de/) on data encryption where we read about a "Passwort" when in fact a passphrase was meant:

> Der geheime Schlüssel wird zusammen mit der Partition / Volume abgespeichert. Dieser geheime Schlüssel wird mit einem **Passwort** gesichert. Die Sicherheit Ihrer Daten hängt wesentlich von der Komplexität (Sonderzeichen, Zahlen, Groß- und Kleinschreibung) und Länge (z. B. 20 Zeichen) der Zeichenfolge des **Passwortes** ab. <sup>[BSI](https://www.bsi-fuer-buerger.de/BSIFB/DE/MeinPC/Datenverschluesselung/Praxis/Software/software_node.html)</sup>

Only recently the importance to make a difference between a simple password and a more complex passphrase was recognized:

> - Im Zusammenhang mit PGP hat sich die Formulierung **"Passphrase"** anstelle von **"Passwort"** eingebürgert. Damit soll betont werden, dass ein einzelnes Wort keine ausreichende Sicherheit bietet. <sup>[Unabhängiges Landeszentrum für Datenschutz](https://www.datenschutzzentrum.de/selbstdatenschutz/internet/pgp/passphrs.htm)</sup>
> - Der komplette PC, einzelne Daten oder persönliche Anmeldungen im Internet werden mit einem **Passwort** geschützt. Für die Wahl des Passworts empfiehlt es sich, auf einfache Begriffe oder Namen zu verzichten. Sicherer sind so genannte **Passphrasen**. Das heißt, man denkt sich einen Satz, ein Sprichwort oder ein Zitat aus und nutzt etwa die ersten Buchstaben als Passwort.<sup>[Internet ABC](http://www.internet-abc.de/eltern/passphrase.php)</sup>
> - Ein Kennwort ist eine Zeichenfolge, die für den Zugriff auf Informationen oder einen Computer verwendet wird. **Passphrasen** sind in der Regel länger als Kennwörter, um ein noch höheres Maß an Sicherheit zu bieten. <sup>[Microsoft](http://windows.microsoft.com/de-de/windows7/tips-for-creating-strong-passwords-and-passphrases)</sup>

These examples also show that we do not have a good translation for passphrase but rather use the same word as loanword. This is made easy as both words *"Pass"*, and *"Phrase"* are proper German nouns which are used to build this composite noun.

---

Rarely we can also hear the Sanskrit term "Mantra" professionals use for a passphrase. This term is not widely known to the public in the context of data encryption.

> Deshalb brauchen Sie das **"Mantra"**, um mit Ihrem geheimen Schlüssel zu entschlüsseln oder zu signieren. <sup>[GnuPG](http://www.gnupg.org/gph/de/manual/c594.html)</sup>

---

In summary in the context of data encryption *"Passphrase"* is well understood by technical savy persons, and more and more by laymen too. Only if we had good reasons to not use a not yet so thoroughly established loanword we may also use *"Passwort"*, or *"sicheres Passwort"*.

Comment: I think that Bundesamt used that word without translation because they haven't had interest in finding one. That's why you can't use that as proove.

Comment: @SchcS: agreed, but those are good points indeed. +1 and thanks.

Comment: Ich lese dein Zitat eher so *Dieser **geheime Schlüssel** wird mit einem Passwort gesichert.* Damit wäre "Geheimer Schlüssel" die Übersetzung von *Passphrase*.

Answer (score 2):

Kennwort and Passwort are both commonly used.

Comment: ... and have a different meaning ;)

Comment: Their literal translations certainly have different meanings but in colloquial use, I can't think of a scenario where they couldn't be used interchangeably.

Answer (score 2):

In computer programs, *passphrase*  is most typically translated as *Kennwort* (even though it would fit the word *password* better) or *Passphrase* indeed.

Answer (score 1):

A chain of words is called `Wortgruppe`. So what about `Kennwortgruppe`? Sometimes it's as simple as that. `Kennwortsatz` sounds too much like a full sentence in its grammatical meaning. `Losung` sounds more like `Motto`. `Parole` sounds like an adventure.

Comment: "Parole" sounds foreign to me and comes closer to "Motto" than "Losung". "Losung" sounds spot on, but somehow old-style. "Kennwortgruppe" is a nice idea. +1, thanks.

Comment: *[Kenn/Pass]wörter-Gruppe* or *[Kenn/Pass]wörtergruppe* may sound even better. Although I like the original suggestion because it sounds plain German.

Comment: I'd understand *Kennwortgruppe* as a set of passwords, each of which can be used individually.